# Arduino serial input value handling

Tags: arduino

If you enter *M* in the *Arduino serial input*, It has to wait to receive the new value in the corresponding if statement, but the contents inside the if statement will be executed without waiting.

```
void Mouse_control(int i){
  Serial.print(i);
  if( i ==1){
    delay(5000);
    Mouse.press(MOUSE_LEFT);
    delay(100);
    Mouse.release(MOUSE_LEFT);
    delay(200);  
  }
}
void loop() {
 // check for incoming serial data:
   while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
    char inChar = Serial.read();
  // read incoming serial data:
  if(inChar == 'M'){
    while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
    Mouse_control(Serial.parseInt());
  }
}
```

Comment: then remove the second `while (Serial.available() == 0) {}`

Comment: do a Serial.flush() before the while() inside the if statement

Comment: @TheEngineer, why? they, don't send anything. flush() waits for TX buffer send completion

Comment: I've done all the above, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you have set for the line ending in the serial monitor.  By default it will send a carriage return and a line feed at the end of your transmission.  If you read out the 'M' but leave the other two there then that's what parseInt is going to see and it will return 0.  Try setting the line ending to none and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I got a hint from comments and was able to solve the problem.
The problem was in dealing with \ n, which required processing at the input.

```
    String char_process()
{
  while(Serial.available()==0){}
  String C;
  String str = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
  C=str[0];
  return C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, the problem is `'\n'`. For a more reliable code, use `isspace` in standard library to ignore all incoming unprintable characters:

```
char c;
do
{
    c = Serial.read();
} while (isspace(c));
```

Then parse input characters into `int`.